# Connect PC to TripleHead2Go DP Edition and to 3 display

Tags: display, displayport

I purchased a TripleHead2Go DP Edition and I can not connect to the inputs and outputs of my devices.

I have an HDMI output from the PC that I need to connect to the display port of the TripleHead2Go DP Edition. Then from 3 Display Port outputs of the TripleHead2Go DP Edition, I need to connect to the 3 HDMI inputs of the TV Sony KDL-32W653A.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any HDMI<->DP adapters? If not, then go get some. :)

From Matrox's [TripleHead2Go FAQ](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/faq/#23):

> **Can I use the TripleHead2Go DP Edition even if my monitors don't have a DisplayPort connector?**
>  Yes. When the proper
>   adapter is used, DisplayPort can convert its signal to DVI, VGA or
>   HDMI. Matrox offers optional cable adapters that enable you to connect
>   your TripleHead2Go DP Edition to DVI- or Mini DisplayPort-compatible
>   equipment. DisplayPort to HDMI and DisplayPort to HD-15 (VGA) cable
>   adapters are currently unavailable from Matrox. Note that Matrox is
>   unable to validate third party adapters.

Comment: first of all thank you for your reply. So, I purchased 4 adapters from dp to hdmi, but I think it can only use 3, because the adapters are from dp to hdmi and not from hdmi to dp. I need an adapter that connects the hdmi port of the PC and enter in Display Port of the TripleHead2Go DP Edition. Could you give me some link adapters compatible with Matrox TripleHead2Go DP Edition mine that can run on my device? Thank you in advance.